# Java Digester for UTF-8

Tags: java, xml-parsing

how to set encoding type of digester in java.Please help

because I have set the encoding type in xml while parsing using digester finally it gives
string something like bytes(grnlà®¨à¯€00) instead of UTF-8 string.

*Is there any possibility to set Encoding type in parser like this ?*

```
digester.addBeanPropertySetter("ECnetGRN/TRANSDATE", "transdate" );--set UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can set encoding to the input stream (xml input) which is passed to digester and it will be taken care.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("name.xml"), "UTF-8");
digester.parse(is);
```